# getting error when running mysqladmin flush-hosts

Tags: mysql

trying to run

```
mysqladmin flush-hosts
```

in order to release blocking but 
got this error :

```
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'
```

how can I run it properly ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to login, and then type `flush hosts`

`user@host:~$ mysql -uroot -p`

then type pass, and command:

```
mysql> flush hosts;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```